# I am getting below error message when change private key to public key using ssh-keygen -y -f (.pem) (.pub)

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services

I run the `ssh-keygen` command and get the `Too many arguments` error. How can I resolve this?

```
C:\Users\sanke\Downloads>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 8273-E957

 Directory of C:\Users\sanke\Downloads

17/07/2019  17:26    <DIR>          .
17/07/2019  17:26    <DIR>          ..
17/07/2019  17:26             1,692 mynewKP.pem
               1 File(s)          1,692 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  12,695,531,520 bytes free

C:\Users\sanke\Downloads>ssh-keygen -y -f mynewKp.pem mynewKP.pub
Too many arguments.
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -i [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -e [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -c [-P passphrase] [-C comment] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -l [-v] [-E fingerprint_hash] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -B [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -F hostname [-f known_hosts_file] [-l]
       ssh-keygen -H [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -R hostname [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -r hostname [-f input_keyfile] [-g]
       ssh-keygen -G output_file [-v] [-b bits] [-M memory] [-S start_point]
       ssh-keygen -T output_file -f input_file [-v] [-a rounds] [-J num_lines]
                  [-j start_line] [-K checkpt] [-W generator]
       ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I certificate_identity [-h] [-U]
                  [-D pkcs11_provider] [-n principals] [-O option]
                  [-V validity_interval] [-z serial_number] file ...
       ssh-keygen -L [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -A
       ssh-keygen -k -f krl_file [-u] [-s ca_public] [-z version_number]
                  file ...
       ssh-keygen -Q -f krl_file file ...
```

Comment: Try removing `mynewKP.pub`

Comment: (Obviously) you are using the command incorrectly. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you know or did you research on how to use this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tldr;

Use `ssh-keygen -y -f mynewKp.pem`

---

The usage text states

```
ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
```

Here the options mean the following (taken from the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen)):

- `-y`: read a private OpenSSH format file and print an OpenSSH public key to stdout
- `-f`: the filename of the key file.

After the `-f` option it also states `input_keyfile` so it is expecting the filename of the input key file.

Your command has the form:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f input_filename.pem output_filename.pub
```

But the command only accepts one filename argument and you provide two. Hence the error `Too many arguments`

Therefore you should use:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f mynewKp.pem
```